# Gitlab push events trigger jenkins on specified branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I want to trigger jenkins to build only when I push to master branch.
But for now, when I push to a develop branch, it will still be built.
I've set like this:
[branch specifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaUJQ.png)

and:
[Allowed branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFwKG.png)

But it seems useless.
Any suggestions about this? Thanks very much

[Build Triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56d80.png)

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your jenkins job configurations `Build Triggers` section

Comment: @DilanTharaka I've added it

Comment: In `Target Branch Regex` try using `master` instead of using `*/master`

Comment: @DilanTharaka I've changed it but useless.